# How to populate the date present in the database table to Calender asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, c#-4.0, calendar

My table in the database has the following columns id , eventstart , eventend , eventname

I am trying to bind the event name plus the event start date in the cell of the calender on the date which it is occurring

However i am not able to do so

Following is my code snippet

```
  protected void myCal_DayRender1(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM event", con);
    cmd.Fill(ds, "Table");
    if (!e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if ((dr["eventstart"].ToString() != DBNull.Value.ToString()))
            {
                DateTime dtEvent = (DateTime)dr["eventstart"];
                if (dtEvent.Equals(e.Day.Date))
                {

                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                    lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Double;
                    lbl.Width = 100;
                    lbl.Height = 100;
                    lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond;
                    lbl.Text = TextBoxName.Text + "" + TextBoxStart.Text + "" + TextBoxEnd.Text;
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);


                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {


      }

}
```

Please help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, once again from the start. Now I think I got it. Your problem is probably caused by comparing date with time to date. To get only date without time You can use `dt.Date` as You can see below. You can consider loading all data on page load because of performance reasons.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();        

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get data
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = 
            new SqlCommand("select * from event", connection);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
}

protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{        
    //mark dates in calendar
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {           
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)dr.Field<DateTime?>("eventstart");

        if (e.Day.Date == dt.Date)           
            {    
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

                //add event lable to day
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Double;
                lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond;
                lbl.Text = "Event text";
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);            
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to bind it to a cell in the asp.net calender and not a gridview

Comment: the data is not showing in the cell that is my issue the label is coming but not the data

Comment: i have already done some part of it when i click the selected date in a calender a modal pop up is shown and the user can add an event corresponding to the date it is added in the cell but when i refresh the page it vanishes and when i run the asp.net page again i am not able to see it in the calender cell though it does get inserted into my database table